# When do you answer a question with "would be" instead of "is/are"?

Tags: word-choice

Sometimes, I hear people answering questions with **would be** instead of **is or are**.

For example:

> Who is that?
>
> That **would be** our new teacher.

Why don't they say:

> That **is** our new teacher?

What is the difference between the two answers?

Answer (score 2):

You answer "*That **is** our new teacher*" when you know this to be true.

You answer "*That **would/will be** our new teacher*" when you are pretty sure (but not certain) that this is true.

Comment: Do people use _would/will be_ even though they know for certain? Maybe for sarcasm?

Comment: Definitely also used sarcastically.  Someone asks 'who is that" (when it's obvious, everyone knows except them) - "That would be our new teacher (who else could it be you fool)".

Answer (score 1):

In this case you use **the 'would' for presumption or expectation**.

> That would be Jo calling. I'll answer it.
>
> We saw a police helicopter overhead yesterday morning. Really? They
>   would have been looking for those bank robbers.

Source: https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-modal-would.htm

> "You have the conditional clear with those examples so on to
>   presumption. That is like guessing. The phone rings, you expect or are
>   waiting for Jo to call and you presume that it will be her. The chance
>   is it may not be her.
>
> Again as it is the police helicopter you guess it must be related to a
>   police activity you are aware of, but again this is guessing, because
>   you cannot know for sure. Any statement made about a certainty of
>   which you cannot know is a presumption. That you may be right is not
>   the point. At the time you make the statement you are presuming." -
>   apex2000

Source: http://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/137940-would-as-quot-presumption-quot-or-quot-conditional-quot